# Use CSV as Array in PHP, input value and output value

Tags: php, arrays, csv

So I would like to use a CSV file as a array.

This is part of the huge CSV file I have.

```
1-1,Poh,ਪੋਹ,19
1-2,Poh,ਪੋਹ,20
1-3,Poh,ਪੋਹ,21
1-4,Poh,ਪੋਹ,22
1-5,Poh,ਪੋਹ,23
1-6,Poh,ਪੋਹ,24
```

So in PHP, I would call for `1-4`. How can I call `1-4`, and then get the output of the 3 values after it, in this case it is `Poh,ਪੋਹ,22`.

Then I make it so `$1 = Poh`, `$2 = ਪੋਹ`, `$3 = 22`.

How would I go doing this?

Comment: Have you tried any code? What error did you encounter?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: @Matt, what do I do, I already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$lines = file('.../xx.csv');
foreach ($lines as $raw_line) {
  $line = explode(',', $raw_line);
  $csv[$line[0]] = [$line[1], $line[2], $line[3]];
}
// then you can access to:
$csv['1-4'][0] // --> Poh
$csv['1-4'][1] // --> ਪੋਹ
$csv['1-4'][2] // --> 22
```

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing, but it may cause issues if he has comma values within the columns that are escaped but by the looks of it, that may not be an issue.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for correcting my typo. Regarding the commas, I agree. Anyway, since this comes from CSV, if commas can be included, the OP will be forced to use delimited mode, and yes, this code should be revised accordingly.

Comment: @cFreed Where is $csv defined?

Comment: @SarabveerSingh `$csv` is populated at line 3 in the above code.

Comment: @cFreed Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$csv' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @SarabveerSingh Please show your _entire_ actual testing code, and tell me which line fires the error.

Comment: @SarabveerSingh You reproduced my snippet _as is_, while the 3 last lines are only informative examples of use, not statements! Try simply `echo $csv['1-4'][0];` and so on...

Comment: It should be `$csv[$line[0]]` instead of `$csv[$line]` :P

Comment: @cFreed OMG! It Works!

Comment: @Matt More and more... I couldn't even edit by myself! :) :) :) But thanks.